# Please merge and synonymize [zmq] with [zeromq]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

A user recently [suggested a tag wiki edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1496022) which is just a link to the other tag wiki. Obviously, the tags mean the same thing, and that tag wiki is completely useless. Please merge and synonymize [zmq](/questions/tagged/zmq) into [zeromq](/questions/tagged/zeromq). 31 out of 60 questions tagged with [zmq](/questions/tagged/zmq) are *also* tagged with [zeromq](/questions/tagged/zeromq).